# Calculate Google Calendar event duration in C#

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, datetime-format, date-arithmetic

I have been working on a C# app in Visual Studio 2013 that will calculate employee hours from Google Calendar events.  I have used this link, https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet, for instructions on how to connect to Google Calendar via the API.  When I enter my hours worked for the day on the calendar, I create an event, and use the From Time as the start time, and the Until Time as the end time.  I can't figure out how to calculate the total hours for the day.  What I want to be able to do is simply subtract the From time from the Until time to get the total hours worked for that day.  I just can't figure out how to get the start and end times into variables that I can then perform arithmetic on.  I can then figure out how to do that for each day of the week, and add them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using example from Google Calendar API, they provide the event date & date time as below,

```
Events events = request.Execute();
Console.WriteLine("Upcoming events:");
if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
    {
        string when = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString();//Right here
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
        {
            when = eventItem.Start.Date;//And here
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", eventItem.Summary, when);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's unbelievable.  Thank you for pointing out my overwhelming lack of attention.  I used: 

Console.WriteLine(eventItem.End.DateTime - eventItem.Start.DateTime);

and that did the trick.  Thanks Nemo.

Comment: You're welcome. Lack of attention happens. No one is immune to that. Enjoy programming!